# How to show the selected value in the url as string in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have used Pug as view file and task is to select value from the select dropdown and then pass it to url. I have got the error "**/users?sortby=[object NodeList]**".

Please find the pug file source as below
`

```
doctype html
html
    head
        script(type='text/javascript' src="/javascripts/script.js")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/style.css")
        h4=page_title
    body
        span Sort by
        select(name = 'sorting' id = 'sort' onchange = 'onSorting()')
            option(value = 'asc') Asc
            option(value = 'desc') Desc
            option(value = 'top 5') Top 5
            option(value = 'bottom 5') Bottom 5
        table#desc
            tr
                th ID
                th Name
                th Email
            each users in userdetail
                tr
                    td= users.id
                    td= users.name
                    td= users.email
html
```

`

My script.js source as below
`

```
function onSorting(){
    var sortby = document.getElementsByName('sorting');
    window.location = "/users?sortby=" + sortby;
}
```

`

I got the output url as below
**/users?sortby=[object NodeList]**

Please someone help me to get it cleared.

Comment: try `document.getElementsByName('sorting')[0].value` or `window.location = "/users?sortby=" + sortby[0].value;` As getElementsByName returns an array. You can use getElementById('sort') and eliminate the use of `[0]`

Comment: Thanks and it works for me using `window.location = "/users?sortby=" + sortby;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be helpful

```js
    function onSorting(){
        var sortby = document.getElementById('sorting');
         alert(sortby.value)
        //window.location = "/users?sortby=" + sortby.value;
    }
```

```html
<select id="sorting" onchange = 'onSorting()'><option value="asc">asc</option><option value="desc">desc</option>

</select>
```